# Error while adding map layer into QGIS?

Tags: qgis, point, utm

I am working on a project on QGIS. I have 50 geographical points. I would like to put on the map.

The reference system is the UTM Zone 36S. I have successfully imported the coordinates but after I attempt to add a map layer I get this notification:

```py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/Athinodoros/.qgis2/python/plugins\openlayers_plugin\weblayers\weblayer.py", line 97, in addLayer
    self._addLayerCallback(self)
  File "C:/Users/Athinodoros/.qgis2/python/plugins\openlayers_plugin\openlayers_plugin.py", line 135, in addLayer
    self.setMapCrs(coordRefSys)
  File "C:/Users/Athinodoros/.qgis2/python/plugins\openlayers_plugin\openlayers_plugin.py", line 176, in setMapCrs
    extMap = coordTrans.transform(extMap, QgsCoordinateTransform.ForwardTransform)
QgsCsException: μετατροπή ορθής κατεύθυνσης of
(-0.285536, -21511.495948)
PROJ.4: +proj=utm +zone=36 +south +datum=WGS84 +units=m +no_defs +to +proj=merc +a=6378137 +b=6378137 +lat_ts=0.0 +lon_0=0.0 +x_0=0.0 +y_0=0 +k=1.0 +units=m +nadgrids=@null +wktext  +no_defs
**Error: latitude or longitude exceeded limits**
```

Python Έκδοση:
2.7.4 (default, Apr  6 2013, 19:54:46) [MSC v.1500 32 bit (Intel)]

Έκδοση Qgis:
2.4.0-Chugiak Chugiak, 8fdd08a

Python διαδρομή:

```py
['C:/PROGRA~2/QGISCH~1/apps/qgis/./python/plugins\\processing',
 'C:/PROGRA~2/QGISCH~1/apps/qgis/./python',
 u'C:/Users/Athinodoros/.qgis2/python',
 u'C:/Users/Athinodoros/.qgis2/python/plugins',
 'C:/PROGRA~2/QGISCH~1/apps/qgis/./python/plugins',
 'C:\\PROGRA~2\\QGISCH~1\\bin\\python27.zip',
 'C:\\PROGRA~2\\QGISCH~1\\apps\\Python27\\DLLs',
 'C:\\PROGRA~2\\QGISCH~1\\apps\\Python27\\lib',
 'C:\\PROGRA~2\\QGISCH~1\\apps\\Python27\\lib\\plat-win',
 'C:\\PROGRA~2\\QGISCH~1\\apps\\Python27\\lib\\lib-tk',
 'C:\\PROGRA~2\\QGISCH~1\\bin', 'C:\\PROGRA~2\\QGISCH~1\\apps\\Python27',
 'C:\\PROGRA~2\\QGISCH~1\\apps\\Python27\\lib\\site-packages',
 'C:\\PROGRA~2\\QGISCH~1\\apps\\Python27\\lib\\site-packages\\GDAL-1.11.0-py2.7-win32.egg',
 'C:\\PROGRA~2\\QGISCH~1\\apps\\Python27\\lib\\site-packages\\PIL',
 'C:\\PROGRA~2\\QGISCH~1\\apps\\Python27\\lib\\site-packages\\jinja2-2.7.2-py2.7.egg',
 'C:\\PROGRA~2\\QGISCH~1\\apps\\Python27\\lib\\site-packages\\markupsafe-0.23-py2.7-win32.egg',
 'C:\\PROGRA~2\\QGISCH~1\\apps\\Python27\\lib\\site-packages\\python_dateutil-2.2-py2.7.egg',
 'C:\\PROGRA~2\\QGISCH~1\\apps\\Python27\\lib\\site-packages\\pytz-2014.2-py2.7.egg',
 'C:\\PROGRA~2\\QGISCH~1\\apps\\Python27\\lib\\site-packages\\win32',
 'C:\\PROGRA~2\\QGISCH~1\\apps\\Python27\\lib\\site-packages\\win32\\lib',
 'C:\\PROGRA~2\\QGISCH~1\\apps\\Python27\\lib\\site-packages\\Pythonwin',
 'C:\\PROGRA~2\\QGISCH~1\\apps\\Python27\\lib\\site-packages\\Shapely-1.2.18-py2.7-win32.egg',
 'C:\\PROGRA~2\\QGISCH~1\\apps\\Python27\\lib\\site-packages\\six-1.6.1-py2.7.egg',
 'C:\\PROGRA~2\\QGISCH~1\\apps\\Python27\\lib\\site-packages\\wx-2.8-msw-unicode',
 'C:\\PROGRA~2\\QGISCH~1\\apps\\qgis\\python\\plugins\\fTools\\tools']
```

I am not too familiar with the program but can anyone advise on what might the problem be?

Answer (score 3):

You get the error from the openlayers plugin. It expects the **project** CRS to be in EPSG:3857. **Layer** CRS can be different.

Furthermore, I wonder that you have a greek locale, but requesting UTM 36S.

UTM 36S is for the Southern hemisphere, and 36N for the Northern. Don't mess up with the subdivisions A to Z, they are not used in the GIS world.

Subdivision 36S is in Turkey and Cyprus, but you should work with UTM 36**N** for that part of the world.

Apart from that, your coordinates `-0.285536, -21511.495948` don't look like valid UTM coordinates. UTM coordinates should always be positive.

Comment: Thanks for your answer Andre. I will look up for it and check how it goes. The coordinates i have are for Cyprus. It is a project that deals with the location in which some endemic mouflons (endagered speices) where found dead. I need to do a map of this. Thanks again